# Communicating with Desktop Apps, calling DLL functions

Tags: tidesdk

I need some window manipulation functions in my TideSDK App (ex.: resize Notepad window), perform SendMessage/PostMessage/DllCall (ex.: to control Winamp) from the app.

Is it possible to setup a communication between a TideSDK App and some AutoIt/AutoHotkey script, to call .dll functions? afaik creating an ActiveX COM object with ActiveXObject() is not possible in WebKit

please give some advices in this area

Answer (score 4):

You might consider getting a handle on this by using python in your app and working with com objects using the win32com module.